# Is there a solid method for wavelet analysis in Python?

Tags: python, wavelet

all. So, I have some time series data that I'd like to process with a wavelet transform to represent thusly. I am relatively new to the concept of wavelets. I noticed scipy.signal has a few objects, but it seems thin. Is there a library or something out there that will aid in this? Any documentation or tutorials you know of will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

Have you tried [PyWavelets](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/)?

```
import pywt
x = [3, 7, 1, 1, -2, 5, 4, 6]
# Discrete Wavelet Transform
cA, cD = pywt.dwt(x, 'db2')
x2 = pywt.idwt(cA, cD, 'db2')
```

There are [a few examples](http://www.pybytes.com/pywavelets/regression/index.html) in their documentation.

The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/PyWavelets/pywt) has more updated information to check out as well.